# How to Use jkmegamenu Twice in A Page, One for Slidedown and Another for Slideup

Tags: jquery, megamenu

I need to use two slidemenu in one page, one is sliding down and one is sliding up, and i am using jkmegamenu, but i don't know how to use the same plugin twice with just a minor change in top position so i created two .js files like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='script/jquery-1.5.1.min.js'></script>   
<script type='text/javascript' src='script/jkmegamenu.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='script/jkmegamenuup.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jkmegamenu.definemenu("mega-product-trigger", "mega-product", "mouseover");
    jkmegamenuup.definemenuup("mega-product-bottom-trigger", "mega-product-bottom", "mouseover");
</script>
```

I also changed the global variable name from

```
var jkmegamenu={..content here..} to var jkmegamenuup={..content here..}
```

And changed the function names (i added word "up" for every function name and change the other codes calling the functions accordingly) but i can't seem to get the slideup work (when it hovers, nothing happens) and there is no error in my Error Console. Any help to make the two js work together or any workaround to make two slideup and slidedown together wound be appreciated.

PS. I am a jQuery newbie.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to create to separate files. All you need to do is call `definemenu` with new IDs

if you look at the `definemenu` function

```
function(anchorid, menuid, revealtype)
```

`anchorid` is the id of the element on which you want the mouse over event to be, to show the menu drop down.
`menuid` is the id of the element that is to be shown on hover over the anchor.
`revealtype` can be click or mouseover

So for example
i want to show a drop down when I want to hover over "Show Me", my code will look like:

```
<div id="anchorid">Show Me
<div id="menuid">
Content for the drop down
</div>
</div>
```

This is the basic setup for a megamenu. Now if you need multiple megamenus, all you need to do is change the anchorid and menuid.